# RenderingTemplate for ListForm Type

Tags: sharepoint, rendering, controltemplate

I created a custom RenderingTemplate "viewInventory" copy of ListForm
rendering template. It looks like below. Then I associated the
Rendering Template to a content type (this is list type content type)
EditFormTemplateName. But it seems the list is not even using this
controltemplate because I put a vogus name for editformtemplatename
and sharepoint did not complaint about it.

This exact scenario works for document renderingtemplate. Go figure.

Comment: Why on earth would you screenshot that rather than paste the code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to associate "viewInventory" with both NewFormTemplateName and EditFormTemplateName of the content type through Sharepoint Manager 2007. (or you could do it feature attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set Inherits="True" in your content type definition, SharePoint ignores your XmlDocuments section when the solution is deployed, therefore your content type after deployment has no reference to your custom form templates.

Set Inherits to FALSE..